# Javascript text link onClick to select dropdown option value (onChange?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onchange, drop-down-menu

I have a select box on a Wordpress Woo-commerce single product page which, when a colour option is selected, changes the main image and displays an add-to-cart button to purchase that particular variation.

I'm building a colour swatch feature which at the moment selects an option from the dropdown via a text link's `onClick` event, but it simply displays the new option in the select box and doesn't load the new image or actually change the variation that is selected to be able to purchase.

This is how it currently looks (which is wrong as the image and SKU haven't changed):

[Default](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByMJ3TZEr-mkMkY2ZUJCeGlTY28)

[When "Black" is clicked (note that the image and SKU haven't changed)](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByMJ3TZEr-mkY2NybjdiRE5wbFk)

HTML:

```
<select id="pa_colour" name="attribute_pa_colour">
  <option value="">Choose colour…</option>
  <option value="beige" class="active">Beige</option>
  <option value="black" class="active">Black</option>
  <option value="blue" class="active">Blue</option>
  <option value="brown" class="active">Brown</option>
</select>

<a class="swatch" id="s-black" href="#" 
onClick="document.getElementById('pa_colour').value='black'">Black</a>
```

Could this be achieved with an `onChange` applied to the select box to properly select the option? jQuery is loaded onto the site so that will be fine also.

Any help is appreciated, and please let me know if I've been unclear. Thanks.

**EDIT: Thanks a lot to both answers for trying to help, but it seems impossible to achieve so I've now given up and used a plugin for the swatches.**

Comment: you need to change the image onchange of dropdowns ???

Comment: It needs to actually "select" the option, which will then tell Woo-commerce to perform its own functions, such as change the image, display the correct SKU and display the correct "add-to-cart" button etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pa_colour").change(function() {
        var src = $(this).val();

        $("#imagePreview").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! 

Rather than just change the image, Woo-commerce does a few other things with the selected variation such as change the displayed SKU and displays the correct "add-to-cart" button, so I'd like to have javascript replicate the actual "click" on the option so that it changes everything using Woo-commerce's own functions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function setSelectedOption(selectID, valueToSelect){

    $("#" + selectID + " option[value='" + valueToSelect + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');        
}

$('#chooseMe').on("click",function(e){   
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var select = $(this).html().toLowerCase();

    setSelectedOption("pa_colour",select);  
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/p36fV/2/

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply too! I think that my question might not have been clear enough though. The select box already displays the correct value so this isn't the problem, it's just trying to get the select box to perform its functions when it is physically changed from a mouse click but using a text link.

Comment: Not yet but we're certainly getting closer so thanks for your help! This did apply the "selected" attribute to the option but this still doesn't physically "select" the option. I don't think the "selected" attribute is actually necessary so we can ignore it for now.

This is how it looks when the page loads: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByMJ3TZEr-mkMkY2ZUJCeGlTY28 , and when "black" is clicked: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByMJ3TZEr-mkY2NybjdiRE5wbFk .

Comment: Not exactly, I wanted the select box to act as a "real click", which would tell a few other functions to run, including changing the image and also changing the SKU. It seems impossible though so I've used a plugin, but thank you for your answer anyway, I really appreciate it.